# Perforce locked all of my files, how do I unlock them?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, locking, perforce

I recently started using Perforce and it has somehow locked me out of all of my files. No matter how many times I try to check-out in my workspace, or submit and then check-out. I also tried the "p4 unlock" command to unlock all files, but then it told me that the files were already unlocked. Yet when I opened my solution, they were all still locked

Is there any way I can unlock my files through Perforce, Visual Studio 2015, or otherwise?

Comment: Maybe you have accidentally created two workspaces, and the files are locked in one workspace, but not in the other, and so depending on where you issue the command (and thus which workspace you're using) the files either appear to be locked, or don't appear to be locked?

Comment: You'll need to say what you mean by locked -- there is a specific concept of a "lock" in Perforce that is controlled by the "p4 lock" and "p4 unlock" command, but your description sounds a lot like you might mean something else, like the files being read-only in your workspace, or being unable to open the files because they're exclusively open.  If at all possible, describe exactly what you mean by "locked out" -- what are you trying to do that fails (other than "p4 unlock"), and when it fails, what sort of error message do you get?